# CSS Transition works in CodePen but not live

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having some difficulty here. I'm learning about CSS Animation and wanted to apply a transition to my portfolio. However, it just won't happen. It works perfectly fine in CodePen, however.

I've looked at a lot of other threads on here, and it seems all of their solutions (such as missing `!DOCTYPE` in the HTML and ready function in the js) don't help for my issue.

Any idea why that is?

Look for this CSS in the Codepen:

```
.img-project:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    transition: opacity 5s;
}
```

And here's the CodePen.
https://codepen.io/SlouchingToast/pen/zprvPw

Comment: Actually CodePen example doesn't work due to lack of `opacity` in `transition` definition. Is Your code, which doesn't work is the same as in CodePen?

Comment: Works when I do it. And yes, it was a direct copy/paste from Atom.